# ¿Cómo cambiar la codificación en Datawriter y Datareader?

Tags: c#

Necesito saber si es posible cambiar la codificación utf-8 por otra que me acepte enviar y recibir bytes en un rango de 0-255, estoy programando bajo C# en windows IoT.

Lo que sucede es que al enviar por el puerto serial valores mayores a 127 se recibe del otro lado de acuerdo al carácter establecido en la codificación utf-8

es decir envío 128 y recibo 194 128,

acá les comparto la tabla de la codificación utf-8 
link: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

la idea es enviar una cadena de bytes, por ejemplo; 0,170,40,15,178

lo que se hace es tomar byte a byte y convertirlo en su carácter equivalente y luego enviarlo, pero necesito que sea la codificación iso-8859-1 o ascii extendido, si alguien tiene alguna idea sería espectacular.

para enviar hago esto:

```
if (j <= 255)
{                                 
      p = Convert.ToString(j);                                
      string da = DecimalToASCII(p);                                 
      EnviarDatoPuertoSerial.WriteString(da);                                                            
}

private string DecimalToASCII(string dec)
{
      string ascii = string.Empty;
      string t = string.Empty;

      if (dec.Length > 2)
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < dec.Length; i += 3)
           {
               ascii += (char)Convert.ToByte(dec.Substring(i, 3)); //valores de tres digitos 
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (dec.Length < 3 && dec.Length > 1)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < dec.Length; i += 3)
               {
                    ascii += (char)Convert.ToByte(dec.Substring(i, 2));     //valores de dos dígitos
               }
           }
           else
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < dec.Length; i += 3)
               {
                   ascii += (char)Convert.ToByte(dec.Substring(i, 1)); // valores de un dígito

               }
           }
      }
      return ascii;
}
```

les recuerdo que es bajo C# pero en windows IoT, y fuera de windows IoT lo solucione agregando esta línea de código:

```
serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

pero no se como solucionarlo en windows IoT recuerdo que programo en C#

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código mínimo que estás utilizando? ¿Para qué convertir a carácteres? ¿Por qué no enviar directamente los bytes?

Comment: lo que pasa es que quiero integrar una tarjeta a mi proyecto y esta tarjeta pues ya envía y recibe de esta manera; la idea es pasar cada byte al caracter especificado y enviar, de igual forma se recibe el caracter y se convierte de vuelta. Pero si se puede enviar el byte sería interesante quizas funcione de esa manera

Comment: Por favor agrega el código a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Cual es el problema en windows IoT? No existe el espacio de nombres `Encoding`? Si existe, simplemente con `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.Conver‌​t(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tucadena)));` deberías convertir de utf8 a ISO-8859-1

Comment: cómo obtengo el carácter por ejemplo de 128 luego de convertir a iso-8859-1, porque eso es lo que necesito para enviar por el puerto serial. De nada me sirve pasar de un formato a otro si DataWriter está enviando el carácter en formato utf-8

Comment: ¿Qué clase estás utilizando para enviar los datos al puerto? ¿De qué tipo es `EnviarDatoPuertoSerial`?

Comment: **DataWriter EnviarDatoPuertoSerial;**   de la clase: _Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter_   escribe datos en un flujo de salida

Comment: y al recibir datos por el puerto serial mayores a 127 me arroja esta excepción  _“no mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page”_

Comment: ¿Y si en lugar de utilizar `WriteString` utilizas `WriteByte`?

Answer (score 0):

gracias por su ayuda muchachos, gracias al dato que me dió -Xint0- de que utilizara WriteByte, lo hice de esa manera pero al otro lado recibía el carácter correspondiente entonces hice lo siguiente:

```
if (j <= 255)
                            {                                 
                                byte bs = Convert.ToByte(j);
                                string bt = Convert.ToString(bs);
                                EnviarDatoPuertoSerial.WriteString(bt);                                    
                            }
```

convertí j que es una variable int en byte y luego en string, he aquí el detalle; la conversión de byte a string si me acepta la conversión del número completo en su respectivo caracter y luego envío por el puerto serial, del otro lado recibo la misma cadena de bytes enviada.

Aún me falta solucionar la recepción de datos, recuerden que para valores mayores a 127 me arroja “no mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page”

----- es cierto que dije trabajo en Windows IoT, es decir; la aplicación se programa en C# windows universal. ----

esto es lo que hago en la recepción de datos:

```
private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        // If task cancellation was requested, comply
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
        LeerDatoPuertoSerial.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream
            loadAsyncTask = LeerDatoPuertoSerial.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);

            // Launch the task and wait
            uint bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                status.Text = "Leyendo bytes...";
                string leer = LeerDatoPuertoSerial.ReadString(bytesRead);

                /*
                string[] valor = new string[] { ASCIIToDecimal(leer) };

                for (int i = 0; i < valor.Length; i++)
                {
                    pp = pp + valor[i];

                }


                */

                txtRecibido2.Items.Add(leer);
                status.Text = "lectura de bytes completada!";
            }
        }
    }
```

de esa manera al intentar leer un byte superior a 127 me arroja esta excepción: 
“no mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page”

Comment: Ya he dado con la solución al recibir los datos en el puerto serial, hay que configurar para recibir en tipo byte y hacer la conversión necesaria.